# Mouseover toggle ajax value

Tags: javascript, ajax, mouseover

I want to get the value from a button to an img's ***src*** when it's ***mousehover***.

```
<div style="float:left;">
<button value="dragon.jpg">Dragon</button>
<button value="phoenix.jpg">Phoenix</button>
</div>
<div style="float:left;"><img src="dragon.jpg"></div>
```

how do I do this?.

Comment: Before asking this type of question, you should let us know what you've tried.

Comment: You're missing all the AJAX.

Comment: i make a list animal that display a preview with picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this mouseover event of javascript:-

```
    <body onload="load()">
    <div style="float:left;">
        <button class="hover-btn" value="dragon.jpg">Dragon</button>
        <button class="hover-btn" value="phoenix.jpg">Phoenix</button>
    </div>
    <div style="float:left;">
    <img id="imgChange" src="dragon.jpg" />
    </div>
    <script>
        function load(){
            var btns = document.getElementsByClassName("hover-btn");
            for(var i =0; i< btns.length; i++){
                btns[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function( event ) {   
                    document.getElementById("imgChange").src = event.target.value; 
                }, false);
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: its work but the last image get focus when not hover. how to solve it?

let's say 3 seconds and the image fade out?